# Memory Issues When Cloning Sections of an UIImage iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-management, uiimageview, uiimage

I am working on an app that copies sections of an image to other parts of that image. The logic to copy works fine, but I ran into issues when I wanted to provide an undo feature.

Current solution was to save an array of up to 5 UIImages and just revert using the second to last object in the stack. This caused all sorts of memory issues when using very large images .  For example it could have 5 5MB images in that array.

These are the two ideas I currently have.

1. Instead of saving a brand new image with all of the changes, save just the changes made like a layer in Photoshop. I can have 5 layers stacked on top of each other and when I run out of layers merge the bottom two layers and create a new layer. I may still run into issues if the user copies the entire image on the one layer. This is unlikely.
2. Save the entire image like I was, but save it to the file system. This will keep memory free, but I am unsure what how intense it will be for the device to be constantly saving 5MB images. I would limit it to 5 images saved.

Any other ideas or why one of the two would be better than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option that I would consider would be implement to the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) by storing the information to make the image edits. When the image is needed for display, it can be generated at that time by processing the current commands. At most, you will have the original image and the edited version in memory at any given time.

That also helps solve the "undo" problem since you can now just remove command items from an array.

Comment: To undo you would have to run the entire list of commands after you pop the last one off the stack?

Comment: yes, undo would require a new image to be produced to show the latest version

Comment: I like the idea because this would allow unlimited undos until they make it back to the starting image. First problem that I see is the need to redraw the entire image from scratch every time they undo which could take a while. Second I have two types of draw methods one being a quick stamp of a section and the other being a dragging method. The dragging method could be a pain to store as one method and redoing could take a long time because it is a bunch of stamp methods linked together. If no one else provides a better solution I will mark yours as answered. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the size and memory constraints, I'd be accessing the images using:

```
NSString *fileLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:extension];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation];

[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

This should be used to save the images to the file system to mitigate memory usage as needed.

Be sure you have ARC enabled! You'd want to autorelease unused objects.

Comment: Sorry, how does that work toward reducing memory usage, editing the images, or providing undo functionality?

Comment: saving the images in the file system.

Comment: it'd affirm #2 on his list above.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. You might want to clarify that in your response.